# Xamarin Forms HTML in Label

Tags: html, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am making a mobile app for my website in Xamarin Forms. In the database I have a field which contains some html.

I am using https://github.com/matteobortolazzo/HtmlLabelPlugin but I can't seem to style my html.

This is my code:

```
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public string BodyStyled => $"<!DOCTYPE html><html>" +
                                    $"<head>" +
                                        $"<style>" +
                                            $"p {{margin-bottom: 5px;}}" +
                                        $"</style>" +
                                    $"</head>" +
                                    $"<body>" +
                                        $"{Body}" +
                                    $"</body>" +
                                $"</html>";

                <htmlLabel:HtmlLabel
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    TextColor="{ DynamicResource BaseTextColor }"
                    Text="{ Binding Detail.BodyStyled }"/>
```

The HTML get executed but p {margin-bottom: 5px;} gets printed above the text.

How can I solve this? Thx!

Comment: This seems to be a Xamarin Forms bug. In my case the iOS version works but Android also displays the stylesheet contents above the html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this one:
 1. create custom control in your PCL project:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

 namespace XYZ.CustomControl
  {
   //convert label text from HTML to simple display form
   public class CustomLabel: Label
    {
    }
  }
```

2. Android renderer:

```
using Android.Text;
using Android.Widget;
using XYZ.CustomControl;
using XYZ.Droid.Renderer;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomLabel), typeof(HtmlFormattedLabelRenderer))]
namespace XYZ.Droid.Renderer
{
public class HtmlFormattedLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var view = (CustomLabel)Element;
        if (view == null) return;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Control.Text))
        {
            if (Control.Text.Contains("<a"))
            {
                var a = Control.Text.IndexOf("<a");
                var b = Control.Text.IndexOf("</a>");
                var d = Control.Text.Length;
                var c = Control.Text.Length - Control.Text.IndexOf("</a>");
                int length = b - a+4;

                string code = Control.Text.Substring(a , length);
                Control.SetText(Html.FromHtml(view.Text.ToString().Replace(code,string.Empty)), TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
            }
            else
                Control.SetText(Html.FromHtml(view.Text.ToString()), TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
        }
    }
   }
}
```

3. iOS renderer

   ```
    using Foundation;
    using XYZ.CustomControl;
    using XYZ.iOS.Renderer;
    using UIKit;
    using Xamarin.Forms;
    using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
     [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomLabel), 
   typeof(HtmlFormattedLabelRendereriOS))]
   namespace XYZ.iOS.Renderer
   {
        public class HtmlFormattedLabelRendereriOS:LabelRenderer
     {
   protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
   {
       base.OnElementChanged(e);

       var view = (CustomLabel)Element;
       if (view == null) return;

       var attr = new NSAttributedStringDocumentAttributes();
       var nsError = new NSError();
       attr.DocumentType = NSDocumentType.HTML;

       Control.AttributedText = new NSAttributedString(view.Text, attr, ref nsError);

       var mutable = Control.AttributedText as NSMutableAttributedString;
       UIStringAttributes uiString = new UIStringAttributes();
       uiString.Font = UIFont.FromName("Roboto-Regular",15f);
       uiString.ForegroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(130, 130, 130);

       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Control.Text))
       {
           if (Control.Text.Contains("<a"))
           {
               var text1 = Control.Text.IndexOf("<a");
               var text2 = Control.Text.IndexOf("</a>");
               int length = text2 - text1 + 4;

               string code = Control.Text.Substring(text1, length);
               Control.Text = Control.Text.Replace(code, string.Empty);                   
           }
       }

       mutable.SetAttributes(uiString, new NSRange(0, Control.Text.Length));

   }
    }
      }
   ```

Hope this helps you to solve your problem.

Comment: So you're thinking that there is a problem with the plugin?

Comment: As per your question, you have tried and plugin didn't support your desired output, so you can try this custom control, that will convert your HTML to text using native references.

Comment: This seems to be working except for <a> tags. Also I get "is obsolete, deprecated" on this code Html.FromHtml.

Comment: Ok I see now <a> tags are filtered out. Is there a possibility to make it work so you can click on the a tags or not?

Comment: Ya, it could be possible, possibly you might need to handle it from above renderer and open that url you find from text, in web view.

Comment: Do you also have a solution with a BindableProperty?

Comment: I don't have any as of now, but you can create bindable property in custom control and use it.

Comment: @MSah Yeah I did that and that seems to be working but the problem is because its dynamic the labels height does not expand after the text is set. Would you know any solution to this?

Comment: @NanouPonette for iOS this should work, I haven't tested though. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/10016/measuring-string-width-getsizeusingattributes by using `GetSizeUsingAttributes` in renderer.

Comment: Or else you can set Max lines on a label with line break mode.

Comment: Also there could be logic like, you can find total width of your device, then after, per character define some size, for total string length go with for loop and at a time when you reach max width count it as a line one. Like wise you will find total number of lines.After that assign height of view as per number of lines.

Answer (score 6):

use the latest version of Xamarin forms

```
<Label TextType="Html">
    <![CDATA[
    This is <strong style="color:red">HTML</strong> text.
    ]]>
</Label>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label